# Python dictionary total range(len(dictionary.keys()) INCLUDING empty keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

The `dictionary` is composed of lat and long info, with a time key, with a range from 00:00 to 23:59.

Not all of the data is complete, so it looks like this:

```
00:00 [(lat1,lon1)]
00:01 [(lat2,lon2)]
00:02 []
00:03 []
00:04 [(lat3,lon3)]
...
```

The issue is, when I run a `range(len(dictionary.keys()))` in a `for` it gets me the out of index error. In my database the first "block" full of info starts at 00:00 and ends at 01:12, which means that the list generated by my code stops there, and it doesn't come back when the next block start at 06:59.

position is my dictionary that contains positions with time as a key

```
for ci in range(len(position.keys())-1):
        lat1 = position[lst_time[ci]][0][0]
        lon1 = position[lst_time[ci]][0][1]
        lat2 = position[lst_time[ci+1]][0][0]
        lon2 = position[lst_time[ci+1]][0][1]
        vmtemp = (((haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2))*1000)/60) #function to estimate speed
        tpl_vel = (dt.strptime(lst_time[ci+1],'%H:%M'), vmtemp)
        lst_vel2.append(tpl_vel)
```

Comment: You have misspelled dictionary in both the title and in your command (dictinoary, dictinaty) Are these what you really have?

Comment: sorry, no they are not the problem, lol

Comment: Actually, if your data is incomplete and you are trying to access data in particular positions, you would get this error. You may want to try, except and set the data to null or none.

Comment: What do you actually expect `range(len(position.keys())-1)` to return?

Comment: When I print `range(len(position.keys())-1)` it gets me the full range (1440 all minutes in a day) the problem is in the empty data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just catch the failing time stamps:

```
for ci in range(len(position.keys())-1):
    try:
        lat1 = position[lst_time[ci]][0][0]
        lon1 = position[lst_time[ci]][0][1]
        lat2 = position[lst_time[ci+1]][0][0]
        lon2 = position[lst_time[ci+1]][0][1]
        vmtemp = (((haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2))*1000)/60) #function to estimate speed
        tpl_vel = (dt.strptime(lst_time[ci+1],'%H:%M'), vmtemp)
        lst_vel2.append(tpl_vel)
     except IndexError:
         print("-I- Time",lst_time[ci],"or",lst_time[ci+1],"does not exist")
```

Some positions have no tuple (or anything), so accessing an item there (that first `[0]`) is out of bounds. It seems odd you're iterating a dictionary in this way though - it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: I`m getting an error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I'm new to coding and I'm  doing this project with my professor, we have a huge amout of data but it comes in chunks... We need to create a time x speed chart, my first idea was to use a dataframe, but as I'm new it would take more time, and we have to finish this part asap.

Comment: @GabrielKochVasconcellos fixed, I had i syntax error in the print.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 'index error' comes when you're trying to index `[0][0]` from an empty list (the same thing would happen with trying to reference `[0][1]`, but the code doesn't make it that far). You'll need to flag that there is missing data so you can do something else with it. Try the below:

```
for ci in range(len(position.keys())-1):
        if len(position[lst_time[ci]])<2:
            ### Do something with the missing data
        else:
            lat1 = position[lst_time[ci]][0][0]
            lon1 = position[lst_time[ci]][0][1]
            lat2 = position[lst_time[ci+1]][0][0]
            lon2 = position[lst_time[ci+1]][0][1]
            vmtemp = (((haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2))*1000)/60) #function to estimate speed
            tpl_vel = (dt.strptime(lst_time[ci+1],'%H:%M'), vmtemp)
            lst_vel2.append(tpl_vel)
```